# Find certain information within array

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I’m trying to set where the user adds one line of text containing the Name(Last, First Middle) as well as id number, ssn, and birthday. Example:  Doe, John Hank        12345678901          123-45-6789    Jan. 01, 1801

I first split it by using “ “ to break it up into the array. I then need to find which array value has the ssn in it. Because the name can change from Sr, Jr, no middle name, etc. the array value can’t be static at like ssn = eachpart(3). Is there a way to search each piece of the array with the criteria for a mask of a ssn?

Comment: Can you change how the user creates the line of text, so that those variable content items are at the end of the line? like LN, FN MN  ??  OR, you could parse from the last item in the array backwards--> BD, then SSN, then ID

Comment: Unfortunately not, I’m trying to make it as easy as possible to get the info into access from another program. The few stamps the users have to take the better. If possible.

Comment: So, backwards, from UBound to LBound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create and array using *Split*:

```
Parts = Split(Input, " ")
```

Then loop this checking for

```
IsNumeric(Parts(i))
```

That found will be the ID.

The next will be the SSN.

Comment: Will the search work even with the ssn having the charioteers “-“ in it?

Comment: Yes. But _spaces_ will obstruct the split.